# Lebesgue measure equivalent definition

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $ E \subset \Bbb{R}^n $.
Let $ C_\delta$ :={ I={I_k}: E $\subset \cup $ I_k and diam(I_k)< $\delta$ for every k}.
Then show that Lebesgue measure of E=  inf { $\sum$ length(I_k) : {I_k} $ \in $ $C_\delta$}.

For this problem I was thinking along the line that if (a,b) is an interval in $\Bbb{R}$ then we can write (a,b) as union of finitely many intervals of length < $\delta^{1/n}$. But I can’t write it formally for $\Bbb{R}^n$.
Can anyone help.
Thanks

Comment: What are the $I_k$-s in $\Bbb R^n$, and what is their length?

Comment: I_k are intervals in $R^n$ . They can be of any length. 
I think we’ll have to split it up in two cases depending upon length of I_k . Not sure though.

Comment: What is your definition of Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Lebesgue measure of a subset E of $R^n$=inf{$ \sum $ length (I_k): E $\subset \cup$ {I_k} , I_k is an interval in$R^n$}

Comment: If by $\inf \{\sum m(I_k):I_k\in C_{\delta}\}$ you mean the infimum of the sums of the lengths of the elements of arbitrary sequences of intervals each of whose union is contains $E$ and such that the infimum of the lengths of the elements of any such sequence is less than  a fixed $\delta$, then your inf depends on $\delta.$ Or maybe I am missing something.